# Pass files to subproject

Tags: jenkins

Given job A that runs job B as subproject via parametric trigger plugin as build step with waiting on the result, is there a way to pass files from job A to job B?

1. With pipeline I simply use copy artefacts plugin, but it's only option for copying from workspace is "copy from workspace of last *completed* job". If there exists only one workspace, it will copy from the last one, but Jenkins may create a second workspace and than it would use the wrong one (I've checked it lists the previous version number).
2. A job can have a file parameter (I have many files, but I can always tar them up), but I don't see any way to set it with parametric trigger plugin.
3. I could construct URL to access the file in parent project workspace, but the web interface requires authentication which would be difficult to set up.

I use the first option with some other jobs where pipeline is fine, but the job I am setting up will be manually triggered and have promotions and it would be seriously confusing if it was pipeline ending with different job than it was started, so I really want to use subprojects in this case.

Additionally I would like to have multiple projects reuse the same subproject passing it different arguments, but the copy artefacts task does not seem to work with build parameters. It expands it, but than says there is no such job though it works when I enter the job name explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like I was blind. The "Parameter **Factory**" option provides file parameter. Only one file can be passed, but passing an archive is always an option.